# g++ Internal compiler error in small program

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

I am writing a small program to solve Project Euler [Problem 21](https://projecteuler.net/problem=21), and I was testing out the early parts of my code when I ran into an unexplained internal compiler error. I'd appreciate any tips on how to re-write my program to avoid this kind of error.

Here's my build command and compiler options:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -Wall -o "pe_021" "pe_021.cc"
```

Here's the error that I get:

```
Internal compiler error: Error reporting routines re-entered.  
Compilation failed.
```

Here's my code:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const unsigned int N = 10000; //look for amicable numbers smaller than N
vector<unsigned int> list_of_primes;

vector<unsigned int[2]> prime_factorize(unsigned int);

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //import a list of primes
    ifstream ifs ("primes_10000.txt");
    for (unsigned int index = 0; index < N; index++) {
        string prime_number;
        getline(ifs, prime_number);
        list_of_primes.push_back(stoi(prime_number));
    }
    ifs.close();

    //test prime factorization function by prime factorizing 12
    vector<unsigned int[2]> prime_factorization = prime_factorize(12);
    for(unsigned int (&prime_and_exponent)[2] : prime_factorization) {
        cout << prime_and_exponent[0] << ", " << prime_and_exponent[1] << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

vector<unsigned int[2]> prime_factorize(unsigned int number)
{
    vector<unsigned int[2]> prime_factorization;
    for(unsigned int index = 1; index < list_of_primes.size(); index++) {
        if(number % list_of_primes[index] == 0) {
            unsigned int prime_and_exponent[2] = {list_of_primes[index], 1};
            prime_factorization.push_back(prime_and_exponent);
            number /= list_of_primes[index];

            while(number % list_of_primes[index] == 0) {
                prime_factorization.back()[1]++;
                number /= list_of_primes[index];
            }
        }
        if(number == 1) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return prime_factorization;
}
```

Comment: try commenting out stuff until it works. unless you can first try to upgrade your compiler, then do that. otherwise there is little we can do here.

Comment: Too many issue, its bit hard to pin out each and every bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by line

```
  prime_factorization.push_back(prime_and_exponent);
```

It seems like putting arrays into vectors leads to crash at least in GCC 4.7.3. First of all, send bug report to GCC developers. Second, wrap your `unsigned int[2]` into class, I think this should work.

UPD: as pointed out in comments, putting an array into a vector is illegal.

Comment: lets throw std::array into the room. oh and it can not work since arrays can not be assigned. a bit bad of the compiler to ICE out though.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Or `std::pair`.

Comment: @Inspired: it's not a bug, in first place. `clang` reports the constraint violation correctly: `error: object expression of non-scalar type 'unsigned int [2]' cannot be used in a pseudo-destructor expression`

Comment: @H2CO3: ICEing out is always a bug, it is never a valid way to report even the most broken code.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for the explanation of error, I wasn't aware of it. But I would say that internal error in a compiler is a bug. Regardless of errors in the source code.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Well, yeah. I formulated my phrase poorly. I mean that the code is not valid, so it's not a problem if it doesn't compile.

Comment: @Inspired You're welcome. My previous comment/apology applies to you too.

Comment: @PlasmaHH: It's a bug but it's not a non-compliant one; the OP's code is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Replaced occuerences of `unsigned int[2]` with `pair<unsigned int,int unsigned>`.  You will be much happier.